# The text I am encrypting with AES 256 has timestamp which makes it unique always. Can I have the IV static in this case?

Tags: encryption, aes

The text I am encrypting with AES 256 has timestamp which makes it unique always. Can I have the IV static in this case?

As per my understanding IV should be different each time so that encryption of the same text results in different value. In my case the text will always be unique due to timestamp. So I am thinking that static IV is fine.

Please advise.

Comment: It depends on the mode of operation: CBC, CTR, CFB, ...?.

Comment: If you are using a counter-based operation mode like CTR or GCM, then no.

Comment: keep in mind that some timestamps can repeat for an hour once a year... aside from that, what's the over-all benefit of discarding a few bytes?

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. we are using CBC and also I want to understand more on comment "some timestamps can repeat for an hour once a year". we are using System.currenttimemillis() in Java.